# How many clones are there?

Tags: orphan-black

As *Orphan Black* draws to a close, I'm wondering how many clones there were / still are.

Of course, there's the core group of

> Sarah Manning
>  Allison Hendrix
>  Cosima
>  Helena
>  Rachel Duncan
>  Beth Childs

A number of other clones get some screen time or are just mentioned in passing.

So send in the clones! Who are the clones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Leda

#### Seen in person

- Sarah Manning
- Elizabeth "Beth" Childs (deceased)
- Katja Obinger (deceased)
- Alison Hendrix
- Cosima Niehaus
- Helena
- Rachel Duncan
- Jennifer Fitzsimmons (deceased)
- Tony Sawicki
- Charlotte (new batch)
- Krystal Goderitch
- Veera "M.K." Suominen (deceased)
- Miriam Johnson (deceased)
- Unnamed Ukrainian clone (deceased)
- Camilla Torres

#### Seen in documents or mentioned

- Danielle Forunier (deceased)
- Aryanna Giordano (deceased)
- Janika Zingler (deceased)
- Unnamed Polish clone (deceased)
- Niki Lintula (deceased)
- Ania Kaminska (deceased)
- Justyna Buzek (deceased)
- Sofia Jensen (deceased)
- Femke van der Vleuten (deceased)
- Fay van der Vleuten (deceased)
- Jade (deceased)
- Effie (deceased)
- Five other unnamed clones (deceased)
- Lisa Glynn (unknown)
- Hundreds of other Ledas seen in Rachel's list

### Castor

- Mark Rollins (deceased)
- Styles Miller (deceased)
- Rudy (deceased)
- Seth (deceased)
- Parsons (deceased)
- Abel Johanssen (new batch, deceased)
- Ira Blair (deceased)

Source on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Orphan_Black_characters#Clones).

Answer (score 6):

We are never given a clear-cut answer to that, though presumably someone knows it. As far as I remember, about a dozen clones have been identified, though I had to look some of their names up.

The list you provided in your question includes every clone that plays a significant role in the show, except for two (one of which you'll meet in a couple of episodes):

> Rachel Duncan, who has always been self-aware and works for the "bad guys".

and

> Tony Sawicki, a trans-gender clone seen in Season 2.

Some that you've seen already, but probably didn't catch their names, are the ones found in Katja's briefcase, which Sarah recovers from her hotel room. The briefcase contains evidence of Helena's earlier victims, and includes three of the European clones you mentioned, all of whom are dead.

We also see at least one more clone's medical records in Season 2.

However, there are a number of incidents that happen in the show which, I feel, are intended to give the impression that there are way more clones than we'll ever meet. Two such cases (I think these are early Season 1, so you've either seen them or will soon):

- At one point, Delphine reads off the list of clones that Cosima knows about to Dr. Leekie, and she names everyone that we know; Leekie's behavior implies that he's got a long list of those names in his head, and is just ticking them off as she says them.
- We know of at least 4 people Helena has killed; however, the way her handler talks about her, I got the impression that her body count is much higher.

Finally, as a HUGE spoiler:

> There is also the next-generation clone, [Charlotte](http://orphanblack.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Bowles), and the male Project Castor clones, both of whom are revealed at the end of Season 2.

Comment: Which episode do we find out the stuff in the third spoiler?  I know the second part of that, but the name you mention does not seem familiar to me.

Comment: same episode: season 2 finale, the little girl at the end. I linked to her wiki page for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the list given to Felix by Rachel in the series finale, there are

> 274 Ledas

It's not entirely clear whether the list includes deceased clones, or just those who are still believed to be alive, however.

Comment: Note: while the list does have Alison, Cosima, Tony, and Krystal on it for sure, I don't see the names of any clones we know for a fact to be deceased.

Comment: And now [there are more](https://www.facebook.com/orphanblacktv/videos/2338799019694661/) anyway...